# What is the main cause for a reference error?

Tags: android

i am trying to run my program but facing an error problem.it is indicating an error sign under the   R   of my reference statement. what are the facts that can create this kind of errors ?

Comment: Please share with us your code, and where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R` is an auto generate file.Problems occur if it does not generate or you did not reference to it correctly:

1. It may be caused if a file name in your /res folder be invalid;so R does not generate.
2. It may raised if you try to reference to `R` in a package that is not main package.
3. In your imports of your class,you may see `import android.R;`  change it to `import your.package.name.R;`
4. It may be caused by an error in your resources.For example an error in XML layout or strings file.
5. You can do closing and reopening your project or going to >Project > Build all (and selecting "Build Automatically").It may be fix the problem.

It is recommended to see [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/885009/1043882).

Comment: yeah i have made some mistakes inside the string.xml file.thank you :)